# How can i match bounding box coordinates for grount-truth and predicted part?

Tags: python, metrics, bounding-box

I worked on a model. and I have 100 bounding boxes for gt and predicted parts. I would like to calculate iou score for each. But I cannot do this directly, because of the orders. Order of coordinates of bounding boxes are different. For example the first bounding box for gt is overlap with 43th bounding box of predicted. I tried to find the matched orders and calculate the iou for each with the following code:

```
for i in range (0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        
        pxmin,pymin,pxmax,pymax=pred['boxes'][i]
        gtxmin,gtymin,gtxmax,gtymax=gt[j]
       

        ixmin=max(pxmin,gtxmin)
        ixmax=min(pxmax,gtxmax)
        iymin=max(pymin,gtymin)
        iymax=min(pymax,gtymax)
    
        parea=(pxmax-pxmin)*(pymax-pymin)
        gtarea=(gtxmax-gtxmin)*(gtymax-gtymin)
        iarea=(ixmax-ixmin)*(iymax-iymin)
        IOU=iarea/(parea+gtarea-iarea)
        
        if 1>IOU>0.7:
            print(i,j,np.array(IOU))
```

but this  time, it for each orders match with different orders more than once even they are not overlaped. for instance:

```
0 43 0.9042958
0 44 0.9875165
0 58 0.9222096
1 16 0.7543962
1 41 0.9221437
2 26 0.90981704
....
```

I cannot take the highest iou score, because some of them are not overlaped with each other even they have the highest iou score.How can I solve this issue?

new version:

```
ious = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range (0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        pxmin,pymin,pxmax,pymax=pred['boxes'][i]
        gtxmin,gtymin,gtxmax,gtymax=gt[j]
        ixmin=max(pxmin,gtxmin)
        ixmax=min(pxmax,gtxmax)
        iymin=max(pymin,gtymin)
        iymax=min(pymax,gtymax)
        parea=(pxmax-pxmin)*(pymax-pymin)
        gtarea=(gtxmax-gtxmin)*(gtymax-gtymin)
        if (ixmax - ixmin) < 0 and (iymax - iymin) < 0:
            iarea = 0
        else:
            iarea = (ixmax - ixmin) * (iymax - iymin)
        IOU=iarea/(parea+gtarea-iarea)
        ious[i, j] = IOU
        if 1>IOU>0.6:
            print(np.array(ious))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your snippet assigns a positive value to `iarea` if both `(ixmax-ixmin)` and `(iymax-iymin)` are negative (there is no intersection in that case) resulting in positive `IOU`.

A quick fix would be this:

```
for i in range (0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        
        pxmin,pymin,pxmax,pymax=pred['boxes'][i]
        gtxmin,gtymin,gtxmax,gtymax=gt[j]
       

        ixmin=max(pxmin,gtxmin)
        ixmax=min(pxmax,gtxmax)
        iymin=max(pymin,gtymin)
        iymax=min(pymax,gtymax)
    
        parea=(pxmax-pxmin)*(pymax-pymin)
        gtarea=(gtxmax-gtxmin)*(gtymax-gtymin)
        if (ixmax - ixmin) < 0 and (iymax - iymin) < 0:
            iarea = 0
        else:
            iarea = (ixmax - ixmin) * (iymax - iymin)
        IOU=iarea/(parea+gtarea-iarea)
        
        if 1>IOU>0.7:
            print(i,j,np.array(IOU))
```

Please note that this can be done much more efficiently using numpy (I can provide an example if you will).

Comment: I did it, but may I ask you that how can I print IOU values? it is inside of np.array(IOU). If I try to run this in another cell or if I assign it to a new variable like x=np.array(IOU), it doesnt give me the all of the IOU. How can I assign it to a new variable? or seperately print?  @MichalRacko

Comment: You can define a result variable before the beginning of the loop: `ious = np.zeros((100, 100))`, fill it with the IoUs: `ious[i, j] = IOU` and then save/display.

Comment: could you pls check my code that I edited again? It doesnt work well I guess I made it wrong @Michal Racko

Comment: Okay, you're filling it right. The question is what you need to do with the IoUs once filled. Do you want to find the biggest value for each i or do you just want to print them out?

Comment: my result is:  
0.9222096
0.9221437
0.90981704
0.94402283
....

I would like turn this into this: [0.9222096
,0.9221437,
0.90981704,
0.94402283,...]

But even so I cannot print IOU in the upper code. If I remove ious, the output is same as I wrote. But if I run the code in a new cell : print(IOU) or print(np.array(IOU) the output is 0.8625543!!?? I cannot see those 100 numbers @Michal Racko

Comment: Would adding `print(np.amax(ious, axis=1).tolist())` to the very end of the script (outside of the for loop) solve this?

Comment: This time it produces 99 numbers for each of matrixes:

[0.922209620475769, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0....., 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
[0.922209620475769, 0.9221436977386475, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,...]